# Add child application in IIS 7 with different Application Pool

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am new to IIS. I have two website one in VS2005 and another in VS2010.
I have set VS2005 website as a site in IIS7. And add VS2010 as a application to this site
with different application pool of framework 4.0.
All pages in of VS2005 application are opening correctly. But when i want to open
web pages realated to VS2010 application(Which is a child application in IIS 7)
I am getting following error.

```
**Could not load type 'JsonpHttpModule' from assembly 'App_Code'.**
```

I have also tried to put this line
       "<"add name="JSONPModule" type="JsonpHttpModule, App_Code"/>
  in VS2010 application's web config. But same error is occurring.

Please help me.

Comment: is this working on vs 2010 perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by deleting just jsonphttpmodule line from vs2005 application's
web.config file.